# Install NEO4J graph database on existing Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: python, linux, graph, neo4j, graph-theory

I have an adjacency list ready for building a graph that has 50,000 nodes and 100 million edges. I want to store this in a graph database. I have decided to go with NEO4J. Is there a way or an instruction guide that I can follow to download and install NEO4J on my existing Amazon EC2 instance for free such that I can parse my adjacency list from Python to NEO4J to create nodes and relationships. The end goal would be to be able to access and analyze the graph via NEO4J and use some of their methods like single source shortest paths, max cliques etc. to pre compute certain scenarios. I am very new to graph databases and don't really know how NEO4J works. I would appreciate if someone could throw some light on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your fastest path to Neo4j in AWS is to use an AMI with Neo4j already installed as in this tutorial. https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-cloud-aws-ec2-ami/

From there, I would use the load CSV functionality to import your data. https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/

Once you have loaded your data, I think you will find the graph algorithms library helpful for computing the scenarios you discussed. https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/

I found the free graph academy courses very helpful in getting off to a fast start with Neo4j. https://neo4j.com/graphacademy/

Once you finish the courses, the Neo4j Certified Developer exam is also free. https://neo4j.com/graphacademy/neo4j-certification/